# how to cast LPTSTR to const char*?

Tags: c++, string, casting

I need to read data entered by user and write it to a `.txt` file.

For reading I use `GetDlgItemText`, which returns the type of `LPTSTR`, then I need to write it into a `.txt` file preferable with `fprintf` function (to be consistent with the rest of the project).

Which order of type casting should I do?

Comment: You cannot cast, you must [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/87zae4a3(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Though you could also use [std::wofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) and write to a file without conversion.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `LPTSTR`, depending on your compiler settings it is either ultimately `char*` or `wchar_t*`

Comment: *Which order of type casting should I do?* -- Never cast string types just to satisfy the compiler.  Either use the correct string type that the function requires, or call the function that accepts the string type without casting.  If you find yourself casting a string type, it means you're doing something wrong, or you are experienced who knows **exactly** what they are doing when they circumvent the compiler error because the types are different

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `GetDlgItemText` which, as you said, requires `LPTSTR`, use [GetDlgItemTextA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitemtexta) which requires `LPSTR`.

`LPTSTR` could either be `char*` or `wchar_t*` depending on your compiler settings, but `LPSTR` is always `char*` so no cast or conversion will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess project is Unicode (otherwise `LPTSTR` is `char *`). Use `WideCharToMultiByte()` function to convert from Unicode to ANSI. But you can also store it in Unicode text file without conversion.